# Вывод даты в зависимости от текущего времени

Tags: javascript, jquery, время, datetime

Есть div:

```
<div class="time"></div>
```

Нужно определить текущую дату и время (например 14 июля 11:30) и если она меньше (раньше), чем 19-00 текущего дня (14 Июля 19-00) вставить в time "14 Июля", если больше (14 июля 19-20 или 15 июля 9-30), то вставить "15 Июля".

Благодарю за помощь!

**Решение:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var date = new Date();

var hh = date.getHours(); //часы
var dd = date.getDate(); //дни
var mm = date.getMonth(); //месяцы

monthA = 'января,февраля,марта,апреля,мая,июня,июля,августа,сентября,октября,ноября,декабря'.split(',');


if (hh < 19)
{
    $(".time").html(dd + ' ' + monthA[mm]);
}
else
{
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    $(".time").html(date.getDate() + ' ' + monthA[mm]);
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: Вы сами как-нибудь пытались это решить?
Или ждёте готовый кусок кода?)

Comment: от вас дождешься:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var date = new Date();

var hh = date.getHours(); //часы
var dd = date.getDate(); //дни
var mm = date.getMonth(); //месяцы

monthA = 'января,февраля,марта,апреля,мая,июня,июля,августа,сентября,октября,ноября,декабря'.split(',');


if (hh < 19)
{
    $(".time").html(dd + ' ' + monthA[mm]);
}
else
{
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    $(".time").html(date.getDate() + ' ' + monthA[mm]);
}

});
</script>
```